# Need help creating a drop down button with Java

Tags: java, html, select, button, drop-down-menu

I am fairly new to programming in Java. Currently I am trying to create a button that when clicked will produce a drop down. For example, you have a user input field that does a google type rolling search and separate from that is a button that when clicked will display a window to the right of it that brings up all available options.

Here is my button:

```
<input id = "mainContainer" type = "button" value = " + ";>
```

Is there a way to create a drop down menu after clicking the button with html or css? Or does this need to be in javascript?

It does not seem that difficult theoretically but I do not know much about java so I don't really have to much of a starting point. I would believe that I would just need an onClick() event that will create a new  menu. I just don't know how to write this out in java. I Also need to complete this project in the next 2 weeks so any help will be greatly appreciated.

If you could provide code with an explanation of how it works I would be probably the happiest dude in the world. Any reference would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you might be confused between what is Java and what is JavaScript. However.. Do you need something like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select2) or like [this](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3)? Also,  your button is not visible :)

Comment: Actually the second example you gave was something that I was looking for. Pretty much just looking for a button I could make into a drop down. I knew of the select feature, I just wanted a single button that would display the drop down. You may have just moved this project forward lol.

Comment: So you could solve your problem??

Comment: Hey sorry yeah I got it down, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own using javascript or use some UI components such as: [jQuery AutoComplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: I didn't post my full code but to the left of this button I created a jQuery autocomplete input already. Works like a charm. I was looking for more of a single button drop down. Appreciate the help though.